# Javascript reading files in realtime

Tags: javascript, arduino

Is it possible to read a file in realtime? Im using an Arduino NANO which is connected to a Button.

What I need is I have to read a button input

Right now I use

```
cat /dev/ttymxc1
```

in the Terminal to get the Button clicks. What I want to do is reading the file with javascript to get the Button clicks OR to set the event on the arduino what to do after the Button is clicked.

Comment: Do you have any way to load the file into your javascript?

Comment: I would use a filereader but i have noticed that there is only a way via input type file and thats not what I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood right, you want to access a serial port through javascript (this means you are running a webserver and the arduino is connected to the webserver PC).

Unfortunately, javascript is a CLIENT SIDE language, which means that it runs on the client. It can do exactly what the client can do. Since the client doesn't have access to the serial port, javascript can't.

A solution can be using a server-side programming language (such as PHP), make a webpage dedicated to retrieving the button state (e.g. getState.php), load it in a hidden iFrame on the page you want to display the status and then attach a javascript function to the iFrame `onload` event. The javascript function should schedule a reloading of the iframe after X seconds. And... you have your button status in javascript.